# Iteratively append pandas dataframes in a single group to h5 file

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I have a small script meant to read csv files from a user input directory and convert them to a single HDF5 file:

```
path = input('Insert the directory path:')

file_list = []
for file in glob.glob(path):
    file_list.append(file)


for filename in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    key = Path(filename).resolve().stem
    with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
        store.append(key=key, value=df, format='table', data_columns=df.columns)
```

What this is currently doing is appending each file (in dataframe format) as a group. If I open it in vitables it looks something like this:

[image]

Also, if I run the script again using another directory, it will continue appending new groups (one for each file) to the root group.

What I would like is everytime I run the script, it appends the file groups inside a new group (subject) in the root. Something like this:

[image]

I feel like this has probably something to do with the keys im passing in `store.append`, because right now its using the file name as the key. I was able to manually pass the keys and append the desired dataframe, but that is not the endgoal i wanted.

Some advice would be great! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

# inputs
path = input('Insert the directory path:')
group = input('Insert a group name: ')

# create a list of file paths
file_list = [file for file in glob.glob(path)]
# dict comprehension to create keys from file name and values from the csv files
dfs = {os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filename)).split('.')[0]: pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in file_list}

# loop though the dataframes
for k,df in dfs.items():
    # store the HDF5 file
    store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
    # append df to a group and assign the key with f-strings
    store.append(f'{group}/{k}', df, format='table', data_columns=df.columns)
    # close the file
    store.close()
```

I ran the above code twice once for the group `sample` and the group `sample1` Below are the results:

```
import h5py
# load file
f = h5py.File('test.h5', 'r')
print(f['sample'].keys())
print(f['sample1'].keys())
f.close()

<KeysViewHDF5 ['untitled', 'untitled1']>
<KeysViewHDF5 ['untitled2', 'untitled3']>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted! Can you please just clarify what is the function of `f` in `f'{group}/{k}'`?

Comment: Glad I could help. To clarify, `f` is not a function: it is a [f-string](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3). It is used to format string literals. It replaced `str.format()` in python 3.6. It is similar to the use of `r` to denote a raw string: `r'some\string\with\forward\slashes'` Essentially, it formats a string with pre-defined variables with the use of curly braces `{}`