# how i can enter a path and create hdf5 file with all csv file in the same path?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I tried this script but I am not able to see the hdf5 file, the script running without errors but I don't see any thing.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

# inputs
path = input('Insert the directory path:')
group = input('Insert a group name: ')

# create a list of file paths
file_list = [file for file in glob.glob(path)]
# dict comprehension to create keys from file name and values from the csv files
dfs = {os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filename)).split('.')[0]: pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in file_list}

# loop though the dataframes
for k,df in dfs.items():
    # store the HDF5 file
    store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
    # append df to a group and assign the key with f-strings
    store.append(f'{group}/{k}', df, format='table', data_columns=df.columns)
    # close the file
    store.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the path to store:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5', mode='w')
```

Comment: actually, the script working fine bust still the same issue the hdf5 doesn't created

Comment: i still missing i can not create hdf5 file if have any other suggestion to convert a path contain many csv file to hdf5 file please advice

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

# inputs
pattern = input('Insert the file pattern:')
group = input('Insert a group name: ')

# create a list of file paths
# file_list = [file for file in glob.iglob(path)]
# pattern exp：d:\test\*.csv
file_list = list(glob.iglob(pattern))
# dict comprehension to create keys from file name and values from the csv files
dfs = {os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filename)).split('.')[0]: pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in file_list}

# store the HDF5 file
store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
# loop though the dataframes
for k,df in dfs.items():
    # append df to a group and assign the key with f-strings
    store.append(f'{group}/{k}', df, format='table', data_columns=df.columns)
    # close the file
store.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your path to read all csv files within. At the end of your path string, just add `\*.csv`, like this:

```
C:\Users\foo\bar\*.csv
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How is my answer unclear? The code, as is presented, requires an input for the directory path, although, if you don't specify that you want to read all csv files within that directory, it will not do anything. This code is actually a copy of an answer to a question I posted a couple years ago. You can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61018053/iteratively-append-pandas-dataframes-in-a-single-group-to-h5-file/61019264?noredirect=1#comment107955876_61019264